# Chain filters in logstash

Tags: filter, logstash, chain

Is it possible to use logstash filters in sequence? 
For example I want to parse message into json then newly created field split by character.

input => filter => filter => output => elasticsearch

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's mentioned in [the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html).

> If you specify multiple filters, they are applied in the order of their appearance in the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In filter conf file keep "field split by character" filter below the "json parsor" filter.